# Books on how to solve euclidean geometry problems

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

I am looking for books on problem solving techniques for euclidean geometry. I found these

- "Methods of Solving Complex Geometry Problems" by Grigorieva
- "Solving Problems In Geometry" by Gusev, Litvinenko and Mordkovich

but I am looking for something more modern and simple which is mainly focused on secondary education (to help future teachers).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not an expert in the field but from my humble perspective I'll give my best try in attempting to give my suggestions.

Have you considered?

1. [Koeberlin's Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1285195698) from Cengage. It has good reviews in Amazon. Personally I have used it and has modern drawings and colors help a lot to visualize what to do. Something which is really helpful in this subject.
2. There is also [Jurgensen's Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395977274) by Houghton Mifflin, both are contemporary and explanations (to my taste) are very easy to understand. It has also good reviews.
3. [Holt McDougal's Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0547647093) has mixed reviews but mostly positive.
4. [Ron Larson's Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/054700835X) from Holt McDougal is highly pedagogical (used other of his books also), although aimed at students I see no reason why a teacher can't benefit from it.
5. Other textbooks you may be interested could be:

   5.1 [Birkhoff and Beathey's basic geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821821016). It has very good reviews as well. One reviewer claims that it builds up concepts step by step, which personally I feel it is the best when you lack of spoting spatial figures.

   5.2 [Clems, Daffer and Cooney's Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201812614). Right from the year of the World Cup in US. Haven't tried that out. Although it doesn't have any reviews, its parent textbook [Mathematics for Elementary school teachers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321448049) has good reviews.

   5.3 [Marcus Horbit's plane geometry problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1258812576). This one doesn't have any reviews but it was on the list of recommended sources in my textbook so I believe goes along the lines of simplicity.

These ones are as well contemporary but perhaps offer a higher degree of difficulty. Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for but it is worth a try.

There's an interesting article which is very related to what you're looking for and I suggest you to take a look, a bit outdated but it is worth to read as well from Charles Buck on The Mathematics Teacher magazine (from a year earlier of Moon landing). It can be [accessed here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27957878) although it is not fully free, I believe half of it can be read by free.

Of course these are the best ones which I could find from my experience, looking online and also from browsing at the sources in my former book's reference pages to other textbooks and recommendations. I hope this may have helped you.